# WPF Datagrid checkbox column checked

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

My datagrid checkbox column:

```
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn MaxWidth="45">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="check_tutar"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Checked="check_tutar_Checked"></CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I want to access this checkbox and change checked property. I try defalut method: `check_tutar.IsChecked = false;`

But didnt work because I can not access the checkbox using name. How can I change datagrid column checkbox checked property?

Answer (score 3):

You should bind the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox` to a `bool` property of your data object and set this property instead of trying to access the `CheckBox` control itself:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox x:Name="check_tutar" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

The data class should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise change notifications whenever the `IsChecked` property is set for this to work:

```
public class YourClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set { _isChecked = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

You could then simply check/uncheck the `CheckBox` of a row of in the `DataGrid`, by setting the `IsChecked` property of the corresponding object, e.g:

```
List<YourClass> theItems = new List<YourClass>(0) { ... };
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = theItems;

//check the first row:
theItems[0].IsChecked = true;
```

This is basically how WPF and the DataGrid works.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void ChkSelect_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView row;
        row = (DataRowView)((CheckBox)e.OriginalSource).DataContext;
        row["DeleteRule"] = "True";
    }

    private void ChkSelect_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView row;
        row = (DataRowView)((CheckBox)e.OriginalSource).DataContext;
        row["DeleteRule"] = "False";
    }
```

This solution is without Binding ,you can get the checked row with the above code